# HTML XPath Searching by class and text

Tags: html, xpath

I want to find all elements in xpath by class and text.  I have tried this but it does not work.

```
//*[contains(@class, 'myclass')]//*[text() = 'qwerty']
```

I am trying to find all elements that have a class of 'myclass' and the text is 'qwert' (these will be span elements)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
//span[contains(@class, 'myclass') and text() = 'qwerty']
```

or

```
//span[contains(@class, 'myclass') and normalize-space(text()) = 'qwerty']
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me. This one did -- "and contains(., 'qwerty')". Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503721/xpath-find-a-node-whose-class-attribute-matches-a-value-and-whose-text-contains

Comment: @Andrey Writing "this did not for me" without telling what you did is not terribly useful. In any case, the above code is correct for the question in this thread, if your situation is different it should not be a surprise that you can't just copy and paste the code.

Comment: I didn't mean to insinuate that your answer is wrong. (especially given the number of upvotes). I do hope however that people will find my link useful if it doesn't work out for them for whatever reason. Regards.

Comment: Well, you're right. Having a cross-link is not all that bad.

Comment: this didn't work for me, this did: 
//span[contains(@class, 'myclass') and contains(., 'querty')]

Comment: ...that's because `text()` only selects immediate text node children, i.e. it finds the `'ABC'` in `<span>ABC<b>XYZ</b></span>`, but not the `'XYZ'`. This answer uses `text()` because the OP did in their question. With `.` all contained text nodes are considered, including the nested ones.

Answer (score 36):

Generic solution for anyone looking for a XPath expression to search based on class and text:

Class is **only** "myclass":

```
//*[@class='myclass' and contains(text(),'qwerty')]
```

Class **contains** "myclass":

```
//*[contains(@class,'myclass') and contains(text(),'qwerty')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Presuming the conditions below:

- The *class* attribute contains only `myclass`
- The *innerText* contains `qwerty` (without any leading and trailing spaces)

You can use the following solution:

```
//*[@class='myclass' and text()='qwerty']
```

Incase the *innerText* contains `qwerty` along with some leading and trailing spaces, you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  //*[@class='myclass' and normalize-space()='qwerty']
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  //*[@class='myclass' and contains(., 'qwerty')]
  ```

Comment: This well worked for me.