# XPath to match @class value and element value?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I would like to locate this element,

```
<div class="item-price">$0.99</div>
```

using XPath which says select `div` elements whose `class` attribute equals `"item-price"` and whose content contains a dollar sign (`$`).

Comment: An attribute is matched with `@attributename`, you can use the `contains()` function on the content. Could you give us your best effort using those 2?

Comment: OK. `//div[@class="item-price" and contains("$")]` but I'm unsure of how to make conjunctions. I've also seen `//div[one][theother]`.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation of `contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains)? You're very close (`contains(.,'$')` would do it)

Answer (score 33):

This XPath expression:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'item-price') and contains(., '$')]
```

Will match all `div` elements of the `item-price` class containing a '$'.

It's useful to use `contains()` in the test on `@class` if you want to match cases where there are multiple CSS styles specified in the `@class` value.

---

**Caution**: For a more robust solution, apply the following technique to avoid unintended substring matches (`item-price` matching, say, `item-prices`):

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' item-price ') and contains(., '$')]
```

Comment: I like the telepathic support you are giving me by telling me about `contains()` because it is very valuable. I like the conjunctive syntax used above a bit more. So I'm torn on which to select as the answer because both are correct.

Comment: You're welcome for the telepathic support.  After nearly 5 years, perhaps you're now able to select one answer or the other to [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) now?  :-)

Comment: For me for the solution with spaces to work I needed to add the `normalize-space`, for example: `//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' foobar ')]` [source](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: @Aidas: What was your `@class` value such that it required `normalize-space()`?

Comment: My `class` attribute had 3 values, in short: `class=a b c`. I wanted to search by `a`. So for me it wasn't working when I tried to apply spaces at various places, for example `a`, `a ` etc. Only when I applied `normalize-space()` on `@class` the magic happened. 
On second glance, this may not be related to this particular issue, still I thought leaving a comment might help somebody. :)

Comment: @Aidas: I agree with your second glance: It would not have been [`normalize-space()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55854177/290085) that resolved your issue.

Answer (score 8):

```
//div[@class = 'item-price'][contains(., '$')]
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML:

```
<div class="item-price">$0.99</div>
```

There is:

- Only one value of the class attribute i.e. `item-price`
- And the *innerText* starts with a **`$`** sign.

So, to locate this element with respect to the value of the class attribute i.e. `item-price`  and *innerText* content starting with a dollar sign (`$`) you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `starts-with()`:

  ```
  //div[@class='item-price' and starts-with(., '$')]
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  //div[@class='item-price' and contains(., '$')]
  ```