# XPath for @class returning multiple @href attributes?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping, extract

I am attempting to create an XPath that will point to the `href` attribute of a button (handling pagination).

My XPath is as follows:

`//a[contains(@class, 'h-data-pagination__next')]//@href`

Which returns the following URL:

`http://www.bestcolleges.comhttp//www.bestcolleges.com/database/?pg=2`

The issue is that the XPath seems to be adding the new URL attribute to the old attribute instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that your XPath is selecting multiple `@href` attributes.**

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <a class="h-data-pagination__next" 
     href="http://www.bestcolleges.com">link 1</a>
  <a class="h-data-pagination__next2" 
     href="http//www.bestcolleges.com/database/?pg=2">link 2</a>
</div>
```

Your XPath will select both `a` elements because both have `@class` attributes that *contain the substring*, `h-data-pagination__next`.

### To fix

1. Make your test of `@class` be more specific:

   ```
   //a[@class = 'h-data-pagination__next']/@href
   ```

   or more robust:

   ```
   //a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' h-data-pagination__next ')]/@href
   ```
2. Or, test another aspect such as the link content:

   ```
   //a[. = 'link 1']/@href
   ```
3. Or, [test a combination of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503721/xpath-find-a-node-whose-class-attribute-matches-a-value-and-whose-text-contains).

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one `<a href=` in your document.

So you get an array result. Don't concatenate it, but use iteration, or select e.g. the *last* href only.

e.g. `//a[0]//@href` should select the first only