# XPath: select element based on inner text ignore child

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

```
<a href="editauthority.jsp" title="Add a new connection" class="link btn btn-primary" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Add a new connection</a>
```

I have an HTML element as above with an *font-awesome icon*. I want to find an element from html using its text.

This is what I have tried so far

```
//a[contains(@class,'btn') and contains(normalize-space(text()),'Add a new connection')]
```

But the problem is `//a[contains(@class,'btn') and contains(normalize-space(text()),'')]` returns the expected value with a new line before and few space at the start, which doesn't match with the expected value of `Add a new connection`

How can I match the element text ignore all new line and extra spaces.

I am using the above XPATH to find elements in selenium testing.

**Update**

Adding Selenium code

```
/**
* Clicks a button based on visible text, this type of button is created using anchor tag with .btn class
* @param text
*/
public void clickButton(String text)
{
    WebElement element =
        waitElementClickable(
            By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'btn') and contains(normalize-space(text()),'" + text + "')]"));
    element.click();

    if (!isAlertPresent())
    {
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loader")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so you want just to select element? I thought you need to extract text... this part about `XPath` that `"returns the expected value"` is confusing :)

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `By.linkText("Add a new connection")` or `By.partialLinkText("Add a new connection")`? One or both of them should work without all the XPath.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to realize the difference between **[Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath/34595441)**.

Change this clause,

```
contains(normalize-space(text()),'Add a new connection')
```

to this

```
normalize-space()='Add a new connection'
```

So your complete XPath would read,

```
//a[contains(@class,'btn') and normalize-space()='Add a new connection']
```

You might also want to avoid inadvertent substring matching on `@class` by using **[this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506026/290085)**.

Comment: The above code doesn't code when there a `&nbsp;` along with text in the prefix

Comment: Your question said *nothing* about `&nbsp;`, which presents its own set of issues and merits its own question.  If this answer helps you with the question you asked, then please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer and ask a new question about normalizing away `&nbsp;`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this expression:

```
//a[contains(@class, "btn") and contains(.,"Add a new connection")]
```

[Example](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ca%20href%3D%22editauthority.jsp%22%20title%3D%22Add%20a%20new%20connection%22%20class%3D%22link%20btn%20btn-primary%22%20role%3D%22button%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ci%20class%3D%22fa%20fa-plus-circle%20fa-fw%22%20aria-hidden%3D%22true%22%3E%3C%2Fi%3E%0AAdd%20a%20new%20connection%3C%2Fa%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fa%5Bcontains(%40class%2C%20%22btn%22)%20and%20contains(.%2C%22Add%20a%20new%20connection%22)%5D%0A%0A&=%22&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)

Comment: The problem with this is, it will also find match any button that starts with Add

Comment: You can more specific point to a needed button e.g. change `a[contains(@class, "btn")` to `a[@class="link btn btn-primary"]`