# XPath for all elements without descendants of specific class?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have CSS selector and was trying to apply it in selenium.
Css selector is `.parentclass:not(:has(.childclass))`. I am trying to get all parent elements which do not have descendent element with class `childclass`. It works perfect in jQuery. But in selenium seems it doesn't work.

So I decided to try XPath. What is the equivalent in XPath to the aforementioned CSS selector? I was able to get worked the following:
`//*[contains(@class, 'parentclass')]`. But this is only first part of the condition. How can I say in XPath that I need only parents which don't contain children with CSS class childclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[contains(@class, 'parentclass') and not(*[contains(@class, 'childclass')])]
```

will select all elements whose `@class` attribute contains `"parentclass"` and whose children do not have a `@class` attribute containing `"childclass"`.

Apply the [space-padding trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506026/290085) to avoid false substring matches if necessary.

---

**Update per OP comment:**

The above XPath can easily be adapted to exclude those elements whose ***descendants***, rather than *children*, meet the stated condition:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'parentclass') and not(.//*[contains(@class, 'childclass')])]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested solution doesn't work. It still returns all the parents. Here is my XPath: `//li[contains(@class, 's-result-item') and not(*[contains(@class, 's-sponsored-list-header')])]`. This query returns all `li` with class `s-result-item` even those with child element with class `s-sponsored-list-header` inside. But I need only those parents, which doesn't contain any child element with class `s-sponsored-list-header`.

Comment: By the way, child element doesn't mean first-level child. It can be on any level inside parent. Maybe, this is the reason why I am getting all the parents?

Comment: I found following XPath works fine: `//li[contains(@class, 's-result-item') and not(.//*[contains(@class, 's-sponsored-list-header')])]`. The difference is only in second condition I believe in this case I am trying to find the child element on any level inside parent. Am I right? Is it correct query?

Comment: You're using the word 'child` wrong, then.  The word you seem to want instead would be 'descendant'.   Per your next comment, yes, you want `.//*` rather than `*` if you want descendants, not just children.  Answer updated.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I needed descendants rather than children. Thank you for helping.