# How to use contains() in XPath?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I am trying to collect information from a webpage and cannot get the correct XPath to find it. Here is a piece from a website:

```
<div class="posted">
  <div>
    June 20, 2018
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to search each page for this divide class that says "posted", then return everything under it as a string. (A messy string is ok; I will just use "if "2018" in "possibleDate"" to search for the year) Here is what I am trying:

```
possibleDate = str(tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, ’posted’)]//@text"))
```

It says that it is an invalid expression.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `[contains(@class, 'posted')]` is not wrong, but I suspect you intended `[@class = 'posted']`. The "contains" version will match `@class="signposted"`; the "=" version won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace the `’` characters with `'` characters surrounding `posted`.

Next, replace `@text` with `text()` to eliminate your XPath syntax error.

Also, you might want to use the space normalized string value of the selected `div` rather than selecting text nodes:

```
possibleDate = str(tree.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='posted'])")
```

This will abstract across mark-up variations nested within the targeted `div`.

**See also:** [xpath: find a node whose class attribute matches a value and whose text contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19503721/290085)

Comment: Replacing `@text` with `text()` still returns an invalid expression error. using `possibleDate = str(tree.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='posted'])"))` did not give an error, but did not find anything.

Comment: Ah, you also have to replace the `’` characters with `'` characters surrounding `posted` in your XPath.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested `tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'posted')]//text()")`,  `tree.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='posted'])")`, and `tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'posted')]")`, but all just return empty strings. I am sure the pages they check contain the appropriate class, but they still can't find them.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with a **true** ***[mcve]*** in order for us to help you further.