# What is the purpose of normalize-space()?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I don't understand very well the purpose of `normalize-space()`.
I think it's very useful. In fact, I always use it when I am doing tests, but I am not sure the principal purpose.

For example, in these two cases, what are the differences?
What is the advantage of using it?

**Example 1**

```
WebElement seleccionLabelCabecera 
  = findBy(xpath("(//div[contains(normalize-space(@class), 
                                  'windowViewMode-maximized active')"]
```

**Example 2**

```
WebElement seleccionLabelCabecera 
  = findBy(xpath("(//div[@class, 'windowViewMode-maximized active')"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [**`normalize-space()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) function *simplifies specification of tests against strings for which whitespace variations are insignificant*.

In your examples, consider that additional whitespace before, between, or after the two class values ought not have bearing on whether your targeted `div` is found.  By ***removing leading and trailing whitespace and consolidating internal whitespace to a single space***, `normalize-space()` simplifies tests where whitespace variations do not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

normalize-space xpath function will remove leading and trailing white space.

[source msdn]
White space is normalized by stripping leading and trailing white space and replacing sequences of white space characters with a single space. If the argument is omitted, the string-value of the context node is normalized and returned.

Example:

```html
<text>
    This is a
  test, with a   lot    of 
    irregular  spacing and
    waiting to be   normalizaed.


</text>
```

Result with out normalize-space

> "
>
> This is a
>
> test, with a lot of
>
> irregular spacing and
>
> waiting to be normalizaed.
>
> "

Result with normalize-space

> "This is a test, with a lot of irregular spacing and waiting to be normalized."

You can get more detailed explanation in the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256063(v=vs.100)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22851646)

Comment: @MG_Bautista  Thanks for the review and input. Added more details.