# XPath containing 2 or more "OR" conditions not working?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, anchor, web-testing

There is an anchor tag, whose value can be changed by the user. Now, i want to write an Xpath query that searches for multiple link text names in one statement itself.

```
<a href="#login" class="fancybox" xpath="1">Signin</a>
```

now, link text value can be changed by user profile. for eg, "Login", "Log-in", "Click here to login" or "Login now"

If i write xpath:-

```
//a[contains(text(),'Login') or contains(text(),'Log-in') or contains(text(),'Login now') or contains(text(),'click here to Login')]
```

Then it fails. I need to click this element using Selenium.

Please help.

Comment: Can you try it like this : By. Xpath(//a[@class='fancybox']) Then click on this element.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I don't know what the problem is, but your XPath expression looks perfectly OK. I wouldn't write it that way (for example, if the text contains 'Login now' then it also contains 'Login', so one of the conditions is redundant); but that doesn't explain it failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Important notes:**

- Only use `contains()` when you need *substring* testing.  See [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669251/what-does-contains-do-in-xpath)
- Understand [***string-values***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value): See [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)
- Beware of whitespace variations.  See [What is the purpose of normalize-space()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55854177/290085)
- Your posted markup has `Signin`, but your XPath does not.
- Mind case sensitivity: `click here to Login` is not the same as `Click here to Login`.

### XPath 1.0

If you're certain there are no whitespace variations:

```
//a[.='Login' or .='Log-in' or .='Click here to login' or .='Login now']
```

Otherwise:

```
//a[   normalize-space()='Login" 
    or normalize-space()='Log-in' 
    or normalize-space()='Click here to login' 
    or normalize-space()='Login now']
```

### XPath 2.0

```
//a[normalize-space()=('Login','Log-in','Click here to login','Login now')]
```

Comment: Hi, kjhughes, thanks for a detailed answer. I didnt knew that we can use comma separated values in OR conditions of XPath. So, is there any limit with the number of "OR" , "AND" that can be used in an XPath Expression. Like can i write 10-15 or more conditions for "OR"?

Comment: Note that the `x=('a','b','c')` construct requires XPath 2.0 or higher.  Regarding the maximum number of operands to `or` or `and`, there is no theoretical limit .  There may be a limit for any given implementation, but 10-15 should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

XPath is based on sequences. So you can use a comma separated list, i.e. sequence, to imitate logical OR conditions.

**XPath**

```
//a[text()=("Login","Log-in","Click here to login")]
```

Comment: The OP is using Selenium, so he's stuck with the antiquated XPath 1.0 syntax. This construct requires XPath 2.0 or later.