# XPath for two different classes?

Tags: html, python-3.x, xml, xpath, web-scraping

Given the example

```
<div class = "one">
<p>This is some text<p>
<p>This is some other text<p>
<div>
<div class = "two"> 
<p>This is some text<p>
<p>This is some other text<p>
<div>
```

extracting from class 'one' would be :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'one')]
```

How do I add the other class 'two', to the same XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class="one" or @class="two"]
```

will select all `div` elements with `@class` attribute values of `"one"` or `"two"`.

For a more robust matching of `@class` that takes into account that `@class` attribute values can be space-separate lists, see [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506026/290085).