# Select text immediately after font awesome icons using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I am trying to extract text that are not nested within an HTML element. Here is the HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>theCity
  <i class='fa fa-link'></i>theEmail
  <i class='fa fa-phone'></i>thePhone1
  <i class='fa fa-phone'></i>thePhone2
  <b>Fax:</b>theFax
  <b>Address:</b>theAddress
</div>
```

I wanted to get the following results

- theCity
- theEmail
- thePhone1
- thePhone2
- theFax
- theAddress

As you can see there have different formats. theCity, theEmail, thePhone1 and thePhone2 have similar formats while theFax and theAddress have another one. 
I tried getting both types of data using the following statements, but it didn't work.

Here is the code I tried for the fax and address

```
//b/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Here is the code for the the city, email and phone data types

```
normalize-space(//div[@class="fa-map-marker"]/following-sibling::text())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

1. For the `i`-based labels, realize that the `fa fa-map-marker` classes are on the `i`, not the `div`.  Also, if you wish to use equality, you have to test against the entire attribute value.  If you wish to use `contains()` for a more robust solution, see [XPath to match @class value and element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19503721/290085) Finally, don't forget the `[1]` to ensure you only get the immediately following text node.
2. For the `b`-based labels, specify the contents of the `b` element before using the `following-sibling::` as you're already doing properly.

Here are the XPath expressions to select each of those targets:

- **theCity**: `//i[@class="fa fa-map-marker"]/following-sibling::text()[1]`
- **theEmail**: `//i[@class="fa fa-link"]/following-sibling::text()[1]`
- **thePhone1**: `//i[@class="fa fa-phone"][1]/following-sibling::text()[1]`
- **thePhone2**: `//i[@class="fa fa-phone"][2]/following-sibling::text()[1]`
- **theFax**: `//b[.="Fax:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]`
- **theAddress**: `//b[.="Address:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]`

Comment: Thanks, your answer works perfectly. But one thing i wanted to know is, what if i wanted to refer to the fa fa.... classes and the b based labels by also mentioning a parent div by id. If we assume that there is another div above the col-md-12 which nests all the above listed with id of 'theList'. How can we incorporate that into your answer.

Comment: would something like 

//div[@id="theList"]//i[@class="fa fa-map-marker"]/following-sibling::text()[1]     work

Comment: Yes, specifying the heritage of the `i` or `b` elements in that manner is a fine way to narrow scope.