# Xpath: Get text within tag containing other tags

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to get a price within a span with xpath. Since it contains a span within, the only value I get is \n:

HTML:

```
<span class="price--default is--nowrap is--discount">
                <span class="price--label">Unser Preis:</span> 19,95&nbsp;€
        </span>
```

Try to get value with xpath:

```
>>> selector.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'price--default')]/text()").extract_first()
'\n'
```

Trying it with following-sibling:

```
>>> selector.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'price--default')]/following-sibling::text()").extract_first()
'\n'
```

How is it possible to get the price with the span tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on track with your `following-sibling::` attempt, but change the XPath,

```
.//span[contains(@class, 'price--default')]/following-sibling::text()
```

to

```
.//span[contains(@class, 'price--label')]/following-sibling::text()
```

because it's the inner `span` after which you wish to select the following sibling text node.

**Note**: If you know there's a single `class` attribute value, use `=` rather than the string containment predicate:

```
.//span[@class='price--label']/following-sibling::text()
```

If there could be multiple `class` attribute values, then use the space-padded idiom described here: [XPath to match @class value and element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19503721/290085)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I also solved it by using: selector.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'price--default')]/text()").extract()[1]. Not sure which one to prefere now, looks like the same result.

Comment: Your alternative will suffer if there come to be multiple text node children under the `price--default` tag.   (There are many ways to make mine more robust too, btw.  I started by mentioning the space-padded `@class` idiom, but other considerations might include limiting the following siblings to the *immediately* following sibling.)

Comment: Thank you, I go with your version now. Sounds logical.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try:

```
.//span[span]/text()
```