# XPath of first ancestor with specific class

Tags: html, xml, xpath

[image]

I have the HTML in the screenshot, I can get the node with text in it using:

```
//div[contains(., 'Property Land')]
```

but now I want to go up one level and then find the table child of the first ancestor.

I tried:

```
//div[contains(., 'Property Land')]::div.panel
```

but this is failing. How to I get immediate ancestor of the text containing node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Parent and ancestors

First, let's address the question implied by your title and assumed solution.

- The parent abbreviation, `..`, can find an element's parent.
- The `ancestor::` axis can be used to select among an element's ancestors.
- The *first ancestor with a specific class* of `//div[contains(., 'Property Land')]` can be selected by

  ```
  //div[contains(., 'Property Land')]/ancestor::div[@class="panel panel-primary"][1]
  ```

---

### String values and `contains()`

Second, realize that your XPath,

```
//div[contains(., 'Property Land')]
```

actually already selects not only the `div` that immediately contains the substring, `"Property Land"`, but also all ancestor `div` elements because their string values necessarily also contain the substring, `"Property Land"`.

Therefore, you only need add a predicate to differentiate among all the `div` that contain the `"Property Land"` substring.  You say you'd like the one with a `panel` class.  Here again, be careful to realize that `contains()` tests for substring – both `"panel panel-primary"` and `"panel-heading"` ***contain*** the `"panel"` substring.  Let's suppose that it's `"panel"` specifically that you want.

Then, use this XPath:

```
//div[contains(., 'Property Land')]
     [contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' panel ')]
```

to avoid matching other `div` elements with `class` attribute values that contain other `"panel"` substring.

### See also

- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)
- [XPath to match @class value and element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19503721/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!