# XPath using classname and contains text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I was looking for an answer to how to find an element that has a class and contains text.

I've got two answers.

- `//div[@class='credit_summary_item' and contains(text(),'Professor']`:
  as in [HTML XPath Searching by class and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466083/html-xpath-searching-by-class-and-text)
- `//div[contains(@class, 'credit_summary_item') and contains(., 'Professor')]`:
  as in [XPath to match @class value and element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503721/xpath-to-match-class-value-and-element-value)

For me, only 2nd answer worked.
Can anyone pls explain the difference for 'contains text' part.? As both answers don't mention it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a demonstration consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="credit_summary_item">Professor</div>
```

There is:

- Only one value of the class attribute i.e. `credit_summary_item`.
- And the *innerText* i.e. **Professor** contains no leading and trailing spaces.

So, to locate this element you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `text()`:

  ```
  //div[@class='credit_summary_item' and text()='Professor']
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  //div[@class='credit_summary_item' and contains(., 'Professor')]
  ```

---

### This usecase

But in your usecase it seems `contains(@class, 'credit_summary_item')` worked which implies the element have multiple classes. So apart from `credit_summary_item` there are some other values present as class attributes.

Comment: I was getting confused in between 'contains(.,'')' and text()=''. Now got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case the html looked like this :

```
<ki5-tab text="Super Boal" ki5-tab="" slot="default-1" selected="true"></ki5-tab>
```

xpath :

```
//ki5-tabcontainer/ki5-tab[contains(@text,'Boal')]
```